# App Store is the wrong language

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, language

I changed my iTunes account location to German (with an Austrian credit card) in order to download a certain app that wasn't available in Danish (my primary language). I was now able to get the app from the German App Store. Afterward, I set the location back to Denmark and entered the Danish credit card that I was using before.

**Problem:**
When I now visit the App Store (on my iPhone), it is still in German. **How do I switch the iPhone App Store back to the language that is set in iTunes?** iTunes has got it right, but why doesn't my iPhone see the same status?

I expected that it would be enough to just plug it into the PC and let it sync itself, but that wasn't the case. **I've just synced** the phone with the PC and that went without problems, **but the iPhone App Store is still in German** while the PC iTunes has the Danish account ("Country/Region: DNK").

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open **Settings** and go to **Store**. From there, choose **Sign Out** if you're already signed in and then sign back in again. If you were not signed in, sign in now. Now check the **App Store**. If necessary, restart the device.

Comment: So simple (and yet, so well hidden) - thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. You can also sign in/out by scrolling to the bottom of the Featured view in iTunes or App Store on the iPhone.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I have Japanese App Store interface from iPhone 4 and English App Store interface from iPad (a Japanese App Store, and neither of the device locals are Japan). The language just changed on me after downloading a thesaurus to iPhone, it won't change it back to English.

Comment: This worked for me, nine years on.

Comment: Doesn’t work for my mum (App Store in Spanish, iPhone in German). 

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (stuck in German store/language). I called Apple support, reset the iPhone, logged into the store, switched to (in my case) my "home" store, the USA. I then restarted the phone and the settings stayed in USA/English.

To reset go to: Settings > General > Reset > Reset all Settings. This doesn't affect your data; just wipes the preferences.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I've been having a similar issue with an open case with the Apple Support and they've been as useless as they could on the matter. I tried this and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Search on safari for an app that is only available in the American IOS store.  (TMZ IOS worked for me).  Click the link to see the app in your App Store. It will say the app is unavailable unless you switch to a different APP Store.  Accept and you are allll good! :)