# Rent foreign language films in iTunes

Tags: itunes, language, internationalization

It’s now pretty well-established that you [cannot change](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/3796/2392) the [language](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/3897/2392) of the [iTunes store](http://www.google.com/search?q=itunes+store+change+language+site:apple.com) unless you also change your billing address.

Fair enough.

But the language setting also dominates the *contents* of the store completely. I.e. I cannot download films that, though available in the US, have not (yet) appeared on DVD in Germany (having a German billing address).

This is annoying.

But it gets worse: apparently I also cannot rent/buy the original version of most DVDs that *are* available.

When I buy a DVD in Germany, it *always* also contains the original voice track. No reason not to include it, after all. Since most film translations are sloppy and generally just incredibly poorly done, and since even the well done translations necessarily lose some of the finer nuances, I always try to watch the original versions of films of which I understand the language, and I know a lot of people who do the same.

So this *must* be a common request.

*Is there **any way** to rent/buy the original version of the available iTunes films?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short (and only) answer: No, you cannot rent or buy movies in other languages. I share the same problem in Spain, movies are dubbed in spanish.

Matrix sounds hilarious in spanish, trust me.

There's no way to change that. The only solution is -like you've said- switch to the US Store, but that requires billing address changes and all the hurdles involved in that.

Comment: Ok, follow-up question: how can I complain to Apple/file a bug and not be ignored? The customer relations experience with Apple is as frustrating as with no other tech enterprise. I really wonder why I even still bother. >:-(

Comment: @Konrad Customer experience is a unique experience for every customer. Apple has a very high degree of satisfaction (as opposed to other tech companies). However your specific "bug" is related to a design decision in the way the store is designed, perhaps due to copyright stuff and simplicity. Encoding another language would require more space, bandwidth, etc. I know what you mean, but I understand Apple. I just hope they will give us the choice to change the language one day. Where to complain is hard to say, you can try steve@apple.com ;)

Comment: I don't imagine Steve will be checking his email for a while...

Answer (score 2):

If you find someone who can provide you a foreign gift card from your desired country, you can use it to create an account and purchase from the store of that country.

Comment: There are actually commercial services for exactly this. However, I was really hoping for a legal, within-the-confines-of-the-contract solution (since this solution explicitly violates the iTunes user agreement, and Apple is at liberty to shut down your account at any time).